# Display integer based value in key-value pair as float (with % symbol) (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, percentage

I am new to python,so apologies if this is a very simple question.
I have a list of dictionaries and one key has a value of type integer.
I want to divide that value by 10 and append a % symbol after it
This data has to be written back to a JSON file.

I want to convert "util" :994 to "util":99.4%
(Divide 984 by 10 and append %).
and similarly "util":64 to "util":6.4%
Do I have to iterate through the list?
How can this be done?

Edit: `def num_format(num, x):
    return str(num / 10)[:4 + (x - 1)] + '%'`

Tried out this function to format.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to iterate over the list. What've you tried?

Comment: def num_format(num, x):
    return str(num / 10)[:4 + (x - 1)] + '%'

Comment: I have only been able to write a function that can format.I am not sure how to iterate

Comment: @Sadaaf edit your question to add this extra info rather than putting it in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines should work:

```
def num_format(x):
    ...
for my_dict in my_list:
    my_dict["util"] = num_format(my_dict["util"])
```

writing back to file is another question and has been answered hundreds of times and is extensively covered by many tutorials...

Comment: Since there are other keys whose values associate to integers as well ,how do I specify which key I want the formatting to be done for.Yes,I know how to write it back to a file,Thank You.

Comment: I don't see that in your example but if all you want is change utils it's even easier, see edit.

Comment: Thank you for your help, much appreciated!